# Tool for the cartography of a complex information system

Tags: architecture, components, cartography

I am looking for a Visio-like tool that would help me draw my information system at the component level.

The design will not fit on a single piece of paper and I would like a web tool with a sort of 'infinite' sheet of paper, and a proper navigation system.

An idea that crossed my mind for example is to use KML layers on Google Earth to draw the information system and navigate it. I don't know though how easy it would be to do a Visio-like drag and drop editor inside Google Earth.

Have you ever found such a tool? How do you handle bird's eye views of your information system?

Thanks for your help,

Jérôme Wagner

Comment: Good question! I am looking for something similar for ages, no success so far. Regarding "visio-like": I believe that this requires a hierachical modelling for non-trivial systems, including functionality for component and interface attributes, interface propagation (an interface implemented in a child component is visible in the parent component when the child hidden) and so on. This is much more than drawing like in Viso.

Comment: Have you search to Graphviz? There are plugins wich let you insert graphviz like dokuwiki plugin. I'm still looking for interactive part. http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: Funny how this must to be the oldest question in enterprise computing yet it doesn't have a standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is very close to my heart. I spent years searching for a perfect way to visualize a system architecture. I can relate to a notion of 'infinite' sheet of paper as well.

I tried to utilize "Second Life" as an infinite surface on which to depict the system. As you fly over the area, you see the big picture - big structures representing the main modules and infrastructure connecting them. You can then descend and walk into the structure to see more low level design elements. Sounds crazy? Believe me, it was.

I was also writing my own visualization software where a system was represented by something remotely resembling water towers connected by multitude of pipes. I went too far but didn't get even close to satisfactory results.

As luck had it, I came across "Views and Beyond" approach some time ago [http://www.amazon.com/Documenting-Software-Architectures-Views-Beyond/dp/0321552687/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321552687). This book fixed me. Instead of dreaming of some magical interactive solutions, I now have a solid and sound approach at my disposal. I simply cannot recommend this book highly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Perforce had something like that a couple of years ago. I remember some ads on Dr Dobb's Journal.

A quick Google search finds [this](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/press/pr131_2010.1_P4Eclipse.pdf).